# Call a method after a local notification was received in background

Tags: ios, background, localnotification

When the app is in the background and receive a local notification, I need to execute a method, while the app still on background.

Is this possible ?

Comment: See this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669544/ioscall-method-when-local-notification-is-received-in-background

Comment: I already tried this one, but it's not working :(